# Is there a Ravenloft Campaign Setting for 4E that ISN'T the board game?

Tags: dnd-4e, ravenloft

I've searched far and wide for a 4E Ravenloft setting. I played it once in 3.5's "Return to Castle Ravenloft" and fell in love with Barovia and the setting (even though Strahd was a total pushover in the end!) About a year ago when I heard about the *Castle Ravenloft* board game I got excited and assumed this was what I had been waiting for, but it was not meant to be.

I know I've read on the official D&D website that there is going to be a revival of older settings (such as Dark Sun) and wanted to know if it extended to Ravenloft as well? If not, is there a good homebrewed conversion for 4th Edition? I've looked for information regarding both, but my searches have left me wanting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[2010 GenCon Preview](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4pod/gencondnd) mentions The Ravenloft Roleplaying Game in Q4 2011, (it's mentioned at 58:00, and some questions are asked a couple minutes later) it's a separate RPG, but Fully Integratable with D&D4e, so I suppose that does count as campaign setting.

Comment: This was cancelled a while back.

Comment: @adamjford — Has it been "cancelled" cancelled or "dropped off the schedule and might be back next year" cancelled?

Comment: @Coreworlder: It was "cancelled" at the same time as *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium* (DDXP 2011), and that has since actually come out. So, I suppose there's still hope, but not much.

Answer (score 6):

Ravenloft is more or less folded into the core game now. The new Shadowfell supplement coming out will have some tasteful stuff you may like.
In Open Grave, we have the stats for Strahd. Everything else you need to convert the adventure should be around if you look hard and get creative.

Comment: I knew about Strahd in Open Grave when I first read it, but had forgotten about it, thanks for the reminder! And I like the Shadowfell setting and what I've seen of the supplement, but it's feel is less occult/horror and just more evil undead, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

### There is!

While "The Ravenloft Campaign Setting" promised to be [released by late 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20130622112818/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4pod/gencondnd) never came to be, the Dungeon Magazine #207 (released on October 2012) featured the "Fair Barovia" adventure/small campaign written by Claudio Pozas, which is all about the land of Barovia and Strahd von Zarovich.

Other 4E supplements that can help you run a campaign with that Ravenloft feeling are the supplements: *The Shadowfell - Gloomwrought And Beyond* and *The Book of Vile Darkness*.

Otherwise, your best bet is to convert either *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft* from D&D 3.5 or *Curse of Strahd* from D&D 5E.

Answer (score 4):

Wizards has been slowly putting things out in Dragon magazine that has a very Ravenloft feel, but like has been stated before there is no official setting as of yet.

Here's one of the articles in question, you'll need a DDI account to read the full thing: http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drdod/20081027

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's an excellent issue of Dragon that I had not read. Both Graywall and Sunderheart are very Ravenloft-esque.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I've found for 4th edition is a fan creation on a Ravenloft fansite named [Fraternity of Shadows](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/). The homepage has a link to their [Library](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/). In there, you will see Jester's 4th edition Ravenloft, which includes a DMG, Player's Guide and Monster Manual. There is also a cheat sheet and an update sheet.

Answer (score 3):

The recently released Book of Vile Darkness has a true Ravenloft feel to it.  There are quotes from Strahd, Cyrus Belview, Azalin and Lord Soth peppered in there.  It's got more mention of demesnes in the Shadowfell ruled by Dark Lords, and rules for their "servants".  It's got rules for Lycanthropy.  With this, and the other stuff released for 4e already mentioned, and some old Ravenloft sourcebooks, you shouldn't have any real issues making your own Ravenloft 4e home campaign.

BUT it would be nice if they would just release something official.  Dark Powers, it would be nice.  Van Richten's Guide to 4th Edition.  I still check the website daily for such news.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently running Ravenloft for 4e. Basically, I've taken the 3.5 *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft* and made notes on sheet paper and wrote up the game as usual in wordpad for my game. I'm 2 sessions into it and it's growing great.

The hardest part is learning the story. After that, it's easy stuff. I have plenty of notes typed out in RTF.

I plan on uploading some my material sooner or later on [my blog](http://d20rabbit.gamergrrls.com/). Anyone interested can let me know on the blog!